# CNContactViewController - Edit button not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, contacts, viewcontroller

I'm currently working on a Swift app and I want the user to be able to edit a contact that they created earlier in the app.  That being said, I'm using the `CNContactViewController(forContact: CNContact)` init function to create the view controller.

I have the following code in a subclass of `TableViewController` which is embedded in a Navigation controller

```
let contactViewController = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contact)
contactViewController.delegate = self
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(contactViewController, animated: true)
```

When the `contactViewController` comes into view, the contact loads fine but the edit button is missing from the Navigation bar on top.  If I hard code `print(contactViewController.allowsEdits)` immediately before pushing it to the Nav controller, it says true, which is weird.

Thanks for the help.

(Note, the contact I pass into the constructor is a `CNMutableContact`, so it should be editable)

Comment: Instead of pushing it, try presenting it in its own navigation controller.

Answer (score -1):

You should add only this to appear the 'Edit' button before pushing your contactViewController:

```
let contactViewController = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contact)
contactViewController.delegate = self

//Here you make Edit button to appear and do things that it is supposed to do
contactViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem? = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Edit,target: self, action: nil)

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(contactViewController, animated: true)
```